# Authorization on a field in graphql-ruby

Tags: ruby, graphql, graphql-ruby

From this [guide](https://graphql-ruby.org/authorization/authorization.html) I don't understand how we can add authorization on a field in graphql-ruby.

I understand how we can deny access to an entire object but I don't see how we can prevent access to just a field of an object.
In my usecase, I want to prevent some queries to access a `String` `field` in my `UserType`.

Is it possible? With the `field` helper?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example:

```
module Types
  class User < Types::BaseObject
    field :private_string, String, null: true do
      def authorized?(object, args, context)
        # Do whatever logic you want and return true if the user is authorized.
        object.id == context[:current_user].id
      end
    end
  end
end

class MySchema < GraphQL::Schema
  # You'll need this in your schema to handle an unauthorized field.
  def self.unauthorized_field(error)
    raise GraphQL::ExecutionError, "The field #{error.field.graphql_name} on an object of type #{error.type.graphql_name} was hidden due to permissions"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [scoping](https://graphql-ruby.org/authorization/scoping.html) in the GraphQL-ruby or use gem [graphql-guard](https://github.com/exAspArk/graphql-guard#inline-policies).

For scoping to work, you should be either using Pundit [scope](https://github.com/varvet/pundit#scopes) or CanCan [accessible_by](https://github.com/cancancommunity/cancancan/wiki/Fetching-Records).

FYI, I haven't used it yet anywhere but seems like both could solve your problem to me.

Answer (score 1):

I used gem [graphql-guard](https://github.com/exAspArk/graphql-guard#inline-policies).

```
GUARD = lambda do |obj, args, ctx|
  ...some logics...
end

field :some_field, String, null: false, guard: GUARD
```

And when I wanted to use only some of the arguments like `lambda do |_, args, _|`